# text cleaning in R

Tags: r, text, data-cleaning

I have a single column in R that looks like this:

```
Path Column
ag.1.4->ao.5.5->iv.9.12->ag.4.35
ao.11.234->iv.345.455.1.2->ag.9.531
```

I want to transform this into:

```
Path Column
ag->ao->iv->ag
ao->iv->ag
```

How can I do this?

Thank you

Here is my full dput from my data:

```
structure(list(Rank = c(10394749L, 36749879L), Count = c(1L, 
1L), Percent = c(0.001011122, 0.001011122), Path = c("ao.legacy payment.not_completed->ao.legacy payment.not_completed->ao.legacy payment.completed", 
"ao.legacy payment.not_completed->agent.payment.completed")), .Names = c("Rank", 
"Count", "Percent", "Path"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: I added the full dput

Comment: ao -> agent
is my preference; if that is too hard; ao -> ag works well

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `gsub` to match the `.` and numbers following the `.` (`\\.[0-9]+`) and replace it with `''`.

```
 df1$Path.Column <- gsub('\\.[0-9]+', '', df1$Path.Column)
 df1
 #           Path.Column
 #1 ag -> ao -> iv -> ag
 #2       ao -> iv -> ag
```

#### Update

For the new dataset `df2`

```
gsub('\\.[^->]+(?=(->|\\b))', '', df2$Path, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "ao->ao->ao" "ao->agent"
```

and for the string showed in the OP's post

```
str2 <- c('ag.1.4->ao.5.5->iv.9.12->ag.4.35',
    'ao.11.234->iv.345.455.1.2->ag.9.531')

gsub('\\.[^->]+(?=(->|\\b))', '', str2, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "ag->ao->iv->ag" "ao->iv->ag"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Path.Column = c("ag.1 -> ao.5 -> iv.9 -> ag.4", 
"ao.11 -> iv.345 -> ag.9")), .Names = "Path.Column", 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2  <- structure(list(Rank = c(10394749L, 36749879L), Count = c(1L, 
1L), Percent = c(0.001011122, 0.001011122), 
Path = c("ao.legacy payment.not_completed->ao.legacy payment.not_completed->ao.legacy payment.completed", 
"ao.legacy payment.not_completed->agent.payment.completed")), 
.Names = c("Rank", "Count", "Percent", "Path"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: I am doing this:
data1$Path <- gsub('\\.[0-9]+', '', data$Path)

It doesn't seem to change anything?

Comment: I updated my dataset... there are no spaces between the terms my dput is:

"ao.legacy payment.not_completed->ao.legacy payment.not_completed->ao.legacy payment.completed",

Comment: I have multiple "." in my strings, can I just take the first two letters of each of the terms before and after "->"

Answer (score 1):

It may be easeir to split the strings on `'->'` and process the substrings separately

```
 # split the stirngs into parts
 subStrings <- strsplit(df$Path,'->')
 # remove eveything after **first** the dot
 subStrings<- lapply(subStrings,
                     function(x)gsub('\\..*','',x))
 # paste them back together.
 sapply(subStrings,paste0,collapse="->")
 #> "ao->ao->ao" "ao->agent"
```

or

```
 # split the stirngs into parts
 subStrings <- strsplit(df$Path,'->')
 # remove the parts of the identifiers after the dot
 subStrings<- lapply(subStrings,
                     function(x)gsub('\\.[^ \t]*','',x))
 # paste them back together.
 sapply(subStrings,paste0,collapse="->")
 #> "ao payment->ao payment->ao payment" "ao payment->agent"
```